# Match pattern from vector

Tags: match, rust

Let's say I'm having this function:

```
match symbol {
      letter @ 'a'..'z' => Token { ... },
      digit @ '0'..'9' => Token { ... },
      whitespace @ ['\r', '\t', '\n'] => Token {...}
}
```

This obviously doesn't work. Is there any way to have `whitespace` use similar construct, without writing this like:

```
match symbol {
  letter @ 'a'..'z' => Token { ... },
  digit @ '0'..'9' => Token { ... },
  '\r' => Token {...},
  '\n' => Token {...},
  '\r' => Token {...},
}
```

Comment: You theoretically don't need the `letter`, `digit` and `whitespace` variables for anything other than aesthetics, since `symbol` is still usable in the arms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine patterns using the pipe (`|`) operator:

```
match symbol {
      letter @ 'a'..'z' => Token { ... },
      digit @ '0'..'9' => Token { ... },
      '\r' | '\t' | '\n' => Token {...}
}
```

But binding match to a variable is ugly:

```
match symbol {
      letter @ 'a'..'z' => Token { ... },
      digit @ '0'..'9' => Token { ... },
      ws @ '\r' | ws @ '\t' | ws @ '\n' => Token {...}
}
```